# set bytearrays in an arraylist to single imageView with fixed time delay

Tags: android

I have an ArrayList containing bytearrays. What i need is to loop through the ArrayList and set each bytearray to an ImageView in my activity one after another and after showing all bitmap images it should start another activity.

I tried with for loop, but it only shows the image from last element of the ArrayList

```
 for(int j=0;j <bt.size();j++){
                        bytes = (byte[]) bt.get(j);
                        prgs.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        bmImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length));
                        counter++;
                    }
                    if (counter==bt.size()){

                        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
```

Comment: You are putting all of them in only one `bmImage'. So the last one will survive.

Comment: how can i make it to show each image for a fixed time period?

Comment: Use a timer....